# Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

Is there a way to get the complete path value after the `requestMapping` `@PathVariable` values have been parsed?

That is:
`/{id}/{restOfTheUrl}` should be able to parse `/1/dir1/dir2/file.html` into `id=1` and `restOfTheUrl=/dir1/dir2/file.html`

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Non-matched part of the URL is exposed as a request attribute named `HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE`:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}/**")
public void foo(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String restOfTheUrl = new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(),request.getRequestURI());
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, attribute HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE contains the WHOLE matched path.

Comment: uthark is right. The value in `restOfTheUrl` will be the entire path, not just the remaining part captured by `**`

Comment: HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE is optional and may be NULL or "" for some implementations. request.getRequestURI() returns the same value and is not optional.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore and is unreliable.

Comment: @DolphinJava updated the solution to work with the latest spring versions.

Answer (score 60):

Just found that issue corresponding to my problem. Using HandlerMapping constants I was able to wrote a small utility for that purpose:

```
/**
 * Extract path from a controller mapping. /controllerUrl/** => return matched **
 * @param request incoming request.
 * @return extracted path
 */
public static String extractPathFromPattern(final HttpServletRequest request){


    String path = (String) request.getAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String bestMatchPattern = (String ) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);

    AntPathMatcher apm = new AntPathMatcher();
    String finalPath = apm.extractPathWithinPattern(bestMatchPattern, path);

    return finalPath;

}
```

Answer (score 24):

This has been here quite a while but posting this. Might be useful for someone.

```
@RequestMapping( "/{id}/**" )
public void foo( @PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request ) {
    String urlTail = new AntPathMatcher()
            .extractPathWithinPattern( "/{id}/**", request.getRequestURI() );
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it doesn't handle servlet prefix and mapping prefix.

Answer (score 19):

Building upon [Fabien Kruba's already excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937448/4376460), I thought it would be nice if the `**` portion of the URL could be given as a parameter to the controller method via an annotation, in a way which was similar to `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`, rather than always using a utility method which explicitly required the `HttpServletRequest`. So here's an example of how that might be implemented. Hopefully someone finds it useful.

Create the annotation, along with the argument resolver:

```java
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface WildcardParam {

    class Resolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

        @Override
        public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
            return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(WildcardParam.class) != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
            HttpServletRequest request = nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
            return request == null ? null : new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(
                    (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE),
                    (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE));
        }

    }

}
```

Register the method argument resolver:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new WildcardParam.Resolver());
    }

}
```

Use the annotation in your controller handler methods to have easy access to the `**` portion of the URL:

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/**")
    public void someHandlerMethod(@WildcardParam String wildcardParam) {
        // use wildcardParam here...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to use built-in `pathMatcher`:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}/**")
public void test(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable long id) throws Exception {
    ResourceUrlProvider urlProvider = (ResourceUrlProvider) request
            .getAttribute(ResourceUrlProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
    String restOfUrl = urlProvider.getPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(
            String.valueOf(request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)),
            String.valueOf(request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)));
```

Comment: Confirming this works with the latest version of Spring Boot

Comment: Also confirming that this method works as of Spring Boot 2.2.4 RELEASE.

Answer (score 6):

I have used the Tuckey URLRewriteFilter to handle path elements that contain '/' characters, as I don't think Spring 3 MVC supports them yet.

http://www.tuckey.org/

You put this filter in to your app, and provide an XML config file. In that file you provide rewrite rules, which you can use to translate path elements containing '/' characters into request parameters that Spring MVC can deal with properly using @RequestParam.

WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- map to /* -->
```

WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
    "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
  <rule>
    <from>^/(.*)/(.*)$</from>
    <to last="true">/$1?restOfTheUrl=$2</to>
</urlrewrite>
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public void handler(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestParam("restOfTheUrl") String pathToFile) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes the `restOfTheUrl` is not returning only required value but we can get the value by using `UriTemplate` matching.

**I have solved the problem, so here the working solution for the problem:**

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}/**")
public void foo(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
    HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    /*We can use UriTemplate to map the restOfTheUrl*/
    UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate("/{id}/{value}");        
    boolean isTemplateMatched = template.matches(restOfTheUrl);
    if(isTemplateMatched) {
        Map<String, String> matchTemplate = new HashMap<String, String>();
        matchTemplate = template.match(restOfTheUrl);
        String value = matchTemplate.get("value");
       /*variable `value` will contain the required detail.*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. You can see how I convert the requestedURI to a filesystem path (what this SO question is about). Bonus: and also how to respond with the file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{userId}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void serveFile(@PathVariable("userId") long userId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    assert request != null;
    assert response != null;

    // requestURL:  http://192.168.1.3:8080/file/54/documents/tutorial.pdf
    // requestURI:  /file/54/documents/tutorial.pdf
    // servletPath: /file/54/documents/tutorial.pdf
    // logger.debug("requestURL: " + request.getRequestURL());
    // logger.debug("requestURI: " + request.getRequestURI());
    // logger.debug("servletPath: " + request.getServletPath());

    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    String relativePath = requestURI.replaceFirst("^/file/", "");

    Path path = Paths.get("/user_files").resolve(relativePath);
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path.toFile());  
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error writing file to output stream. Path: '" + path + "', requestURI: '" + requestURI + "'");
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static String MAPPING = "/foo/*";

@RequestMapping(value = MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void foo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    final String mapping = getMapping("foo").replace("*", ""); 
    final String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    final String restOfPath = url.replace(mapping, "");
    System.out.println(restOfPath);
}

private String getMapping(String methodName) {
    Method methods[] = this.getClass().getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        if (methods[i].getName() == methodName) {
            String mapping[] = methods[i].getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value();
            if (mapping.length > 0) {
                return mapping[mapping.length - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon @Daniel Jay Marcaida answer

```
@RequestMapping( "/{id}/**" )
public void foo( @PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request ) {
    String restOfUrl = new AntPathMatcher()
           .extractPathWithinPattern(
            request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(),
            request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE).toString());
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping( "/{id}/**" )
public void foo( @PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request ) {
    String restOfUrl = new AntPathMatcher()
    .extractPathWithinPattern(
            request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(),
            request.getServletPath());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have a similar problem and I resolved in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{siteCode}/**/{fileName}.{fileExtension}")
public HttpEntity<byte[]> getResource(@PathVariable String siteCode,
        @PathVariable String fileName, @PathVariable String fileExtension,
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
    String fullPath = req.getPathInfo();
    // Calling http://localhost:8080/SiteXX/images/argentine/flag.jpg
    // fullPath conentent: /SiteXX/images/argentine/flag.jpg
}
```

Note that `req.getPathInfo()` will return the complete path (with `{siteCode}` and `{fileName}.{fileExtension}`) so you will have to process conveniently.

Comment: this answer is no worse than the accepted answer - it also returns the full path see: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo--
_Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string and will start with a "/" character._