# Match the "Rest of the URL" using Spring 3 RequestMapping Annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

In Spring 3, is there a way to capture `rest/of/the/url` in the following URL:

```
/myapp/foo/bar/rest/of/the/url
```

by using a @RequestMapping annotation like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{appname}/{path1}/{path2}/{remainder}")
public String myRequestMethod(
    @PathVariable("appname") String appName, 
    PathVariable("path1") String path1, 
    PathVariable("path2") String path2,
    PathVariable("remainder") String remainder)
```

I would like the RequestMapping to match like this

```
{appname}   -> myapp
{path1}     -> foo
{path2}     -> bar
{remainder} -> rest/of/the/url
```

In the [Javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) for RequestMapping there is a note about using an alternate regular expression:

> By default, the URI template will match against the regular expression [^.]* (i.e. any character other than period), but this can be changed by specifying another regular expression, like so: /hotels/{hotel:\d+}

But this doesn't behave as expected (I get 404) when I use a RequestMapping like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{appname}/{path1}/{path2}/{remainder:.[\\S]*}")
```

Does anyone know how to match the rest of an URL with a Spring RequestMapping?

Comment: You're absolutely right.  It is a duplicate.

Comment: it is, but I like the phrasing of this question better.

Answer (score 47):

Funny thing: I just came across the need to do this too.  Here's how I solved it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/someChildUrlIfYouWant/**"}
```

The `"**"` here says 'grab anything at any sub-path of what's to the left of me.'  If you want the path it actually matched to get to this method, you can use:

```
request.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE )
```

You will get `/someChildUrlIfYouWant/the/full/path/to/whatever.html` so if you just want the variable child path, you'll have to trim the front part of the string.

Make sense?

Comment: I did same, too bad there is not a better options because if you change the name of your endpoint, it won't work anymore

Answer (score 8):

For the above try:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{appname}/{path1}/{path2}/{remainder:.+}")
```

The default behavior of Spring to stop matching on '.' in urls is not very intuitive.  I don't think period character has any special meaning in the context of the path(as opposed to say '/', ';' or '?').

Comment: Hey, this is so close to what I want, but it does not work as I would expect. If I were to request the url 

     someappname/apath/anotherpath/whatever.file

I *would* be able to retrieve the remainder path variable as 

     whatever.file

However, if I were to request 

     someappname/apath/anotherpath/and/an/other/path/whatever.file

the pattern you supplied (.+) would not match, when I would have thought I would have got the value

     and/an/other/path/whatever.file

Can you or somebody else reading this suggest which pattern I should use to get the url remainder?

Comment: `@RequestMapping("{appname}/{path1}/{path2}/{remainder:.*}")`

Comment: @dgeske It doesn't work.

Comment: You should use http://stackoverflow.com/a/11248730/190713.  That works.

Comment: This only worked for me if the remainder did not contain any slashes.