# Spring MVC wildcard

Tags: spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Does anyone knows how to map everything under a certain URL and then catch that mapped value into a request variable?

```
@RequestMapping("/content/{path:.*}") // matches only one level
@RequestMapping("/content/**")        // matches everything, can't catch
                                      // the actual value matched by the two stars
@RequestMapping("/content/{path:**}") // does not compute
```

What I need to map is:

```
/content/a.gif
/content/a/b.gif
/content/a/b/c.gif
/content/a/b/c/d.gif
```

It's really frustrating because it is such a common scenario.

Comment: Answered here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3686956/249327

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I don't ask Google the right questions.