# Spring request mapping wildcard exceptions

Tags: spring, url, spring-mvc

Can I put /** wildcard in a middle of request mapping such as:  "/some/resource/**/somthing"

In Spring 3 I can do this

```
@RequestMapping("/some/resource/**")
```

to map

```
/some/resource/A  -> ControllerMethod1
/some/resource/A/B -> ControllerMethod1
/some/resource/A/B/C/D/E/F -> ControllerMethod1
```

for any number of paths parts

However this mapping is too greedy and will not allow me to map a sub URL `@RequestMapping("/some/resource/**/somthing")` to another controller such as

```
/some/resource/A/somthing  -> ControllerMethod2
/some/resource/A/B/somthing -> ControllerMethod2
/some/resource/A/B/C/D/E/F/somthing -> ControllerMethod2
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I thinks it's not possible to use that ant style in url mapping as you require, because it will stop on the next path separator character '**/**'.

I would suggest you to try [16.3.2.2. URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) in order to map just the last part of the request (haven't tried this approach yet).

Also you can match the rest of the request using **PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE**, and apply some expression there. [Check this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Otherwise you should use request parameters to match that condition [16.3.2.6. Request Parameters and Header Values](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers).

> You can narrow request matching through request parameter conditions such as "myParam", "!myParam", or "myParam=myValue". The first two test for request parameter presense/absence and the third for a specific parameter value. Here is an example with a request parameter value condition.

In this case you will map something like that using params

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/some/resource/**"},  params="somthing")
```

or use the annotation request parameter with not required attribute in method signature:

```
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "somthing", required=false) String str) {
```