# Alternative to forward slash spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I need to create and capture the path using spring dynamic paths as following:

`http://myHost/event/my/dynamic/path`

In other words, I need capture whatever it comes after event. The path after event is dynamic. This means, I don't know neither what the the values in between the `/` neither how many `/` I will get. I know that the `/` cannot be capture. I'm searching alternatives to do this that doesn't force me to replace the `/`. Something like a query, but that works for POST and PUT.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring request mapping wildcard exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981012/spring-request-mapping-wildcard-exceptions)

Comment: Where do you need to capture the path ? in the page or in the controller ?