# Spring MVC: How to map server unknown URLs to the main application page?

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, spring-mvc

We're using angular-route to map URLs to templates. The application works in a way that if for e.g. we're navigating from `http://servername/appName` to `http://servername/appName/page1`, the URL on the browser changes and the templates loads successfully.

The problem is that when the page is refreshed (or accessing directly `http://servername/appName/page1`), we're getting 404 error from the server. It seems like the default handler does not map unknown URLs to the default app page.

How can we make make the server return the default app page for all these angularjs URLs?

The code is below:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "/WEB-INF/views/nbcalendar.html";
    }
}
```

app configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.appname.web"})
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a error handler in the web.xml configuration. Note! This web.xml configures your app inside the Servlet container (E.G. tomcat), it's not a Spring-MVC setting.

Add something like:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/MY_HANDLER</location>
</error-page>
```

Where MY_HANDLER either is your default location, or something like a jsp that logs the event then forwards to the default location.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Will try that, but isn't there a Spring MVC built-in methodology for this?

Comment: Tomcat handles requests and then dispatches to Spring MVC if the requests are valid. Thus, it's the Servlet containers responsibility to handle 404 errors (or a web server like Apache is that is the front end process). Your web app could contain Spring MVC controller servlets and non-spring servlets. Thus, you want the web app, not Spring to handle http exceptions like a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wildcard expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686956/1636314) in your `@RequestMapping` to match your application and all it's subpages.

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public String home() {
    return "/WEB-INF/views/nbcalendar.html";
}
```

Comment: Tried that but somehow it created an infinite loop. Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding the additional URLs to the home controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static String DEFUALT_PAGE = "/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp";
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return DEFUALT_PAGE;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return DEFUALT_PAGE;
   }

    @RequestMapping("/cluster/{id}")
    public String cluster() {
        return DEFUALT_PAGE;
   }
}
```

This isn't a generic solution and requires to add any new URL manually, but it's working well