# What is the correct way to obtain an entity from a link in spring-hateoas?

Tags: spring, hateoas, spring-hateoas

What is the best practice for obtaining an entity from a link in `spring-hateoas`?

I have two independent entities, `author` and `document`, where documents have can have multiple authors, but authors can exist without being linked to any documents.

To fetch the authors for a given document, there is an endpoint at `/documents/{id}/authors` which returns a list of the authors and their links.

An author is added to a document by issuing a `POST` of a link entity to `/documents/{id}/authors` where the entity contents are the same as a `org.springframework.hateoas.Link`, that is to say a `rel` and an `href`:

```
{
 "rel": "author", 
 "href": "http://localhost:8081/authors/50"
}
```

I want to be able to do a service call like:

```
service.addAuthor(documentId, authorId);
```

`documentId` is provided as a `@PathVariable`, while `authorId` is embedded in the `href`.

In order to get `authorId`, I currently use spring's `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and the controller class for the entity type (author in this case) to fetch the `RequestMapping` for the entity's GET method and fetch the `id` uri template variable for the `href` provided in the link. Finally, I have to parse this as a number.

Is there some better/built-in way of doing this?

Using `spring-hateoas` 0.17.0, if that is relevant.

Comment: I would generally create an additional `key` property of the `AuthorResource` (or whatever you called it). That tends to be useful if you want a simple POST endpoint taking a couple of IDs. However, if you have just retrieved the JSON for an author resource, then you can always just PUT it to the `documents/{id}/authors` endpoint. That endpoint can take a `@RequestBody AuthorResource` argument, from which you can get the author ID.

Comment: Regarding your last point; I don't serialize the ID or the URL as a part of the entity, so although I would be able to deserialize an `AuthorDTO`, I don't see how I would be able to fetch the actual entity from this information. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm assuming that by making a GET to `authors/{id}`, you would get a JSON representation of that author (your `AuthorDTO`?). In which case you should be able to PUT that to an endpoint. If that endpoint accepts an author as a `@RequestBody`, then you can get the ID from the author and call your service. btw - Am I right in thinking that you're using Spring Data REST, rather than using Spring HATEOAS directly? If you were using Spring HATEOAS directly, you could easily add links to resources.

Comment: No, I am not using `spring-data-rest`.  "get the ID from the author" <-- how would I do this when ID is not serialized as a part of the DTO? Is there some magic I am missing?

Comment: How are you generating a URL such as `http://localhost:8081/authors/50`, if the resource assembler has no way to see that the ID is 50?

Comment: The entity has an ID, generated by the DB upon creation. The DTO has no id field; the user of the API saves the entire link rather than just the numeric id. The assembler is working with the entity, where it always has access to the id.

Comment: If you add the ID to the `ResourceSupport` object (the DTO you refer to?) you are returning from your controller, then it's available for you to play with. Is there a particular constraint of your application, that you haven't told us about, preventing you from including the ID as a property of the resource?

Comment: It is a design decision to not expose the ID as a field to the client; they should only care about the URI of the entity. I don't really see why PUTing the entire author entity to `documents/{id}/authors/` is a better solution than extracting the id from an URI.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26348463/2151351) answer.

Comment: @zeroflagL This is essentially what I am already doing.

Comment: Spring Data REST does essentially the same, except that it uses `UriTemplate.match`. So no, there isn't a better built-in way. Btw: It's preferable to post a uri list.