# using spring @PathVariable to extract and parse parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347868/spring-utility-for-parsing-uris) useful thread explaining how to use spring to extract the variables from path to the `Map<String,String>`.
I would like to go even further and parse those variables into type using spring, but unfortunately i'm unable to do so.

format: `"/mypath/[{varaible}]/something"`

input: `"/mypath/[0.0,0.1,0.2]/something"`

output: `Double[] myArray`

Is it possible to use spring functionality for this?

Comment: spring only provides parameters from original request in string format at the moment. I would say no, unless you rewrite part of the core functionality

Comment: are you trying to input an array of decimals?

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)

Comment: @SalmanKazmi yes, i'm trying to parse an array, as they do in RequestMapping, but i don't want it as endpoint. please check post i mentioned in question, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this syntax (not tested, but quite sure...):

```
@RequestMapping("/mypath/{doubles}/something")
public String aControllerMethod(@PathVariable("doubles") Double[] arrayOfDoubles) { ... }
```

and executing the request this way:

```
/mypath/0.0,0.1,0.2/something
```