# Spring-Boot @RequestMapping and @PathVariable with regular expression matching

Tags: regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, webjars

I'm attempting to use WebJars-Locator with a Spring-Boot application to map JAR resources.  As per their [website](http://www.webjars.org/documentation), I created a RequestMapping like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/webjars-locator/{webjar}/{partialPath:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<ClassPathResource> locateWebjarAsset(@PathVariable String webjar, @PathVariable String partialPath)
{
```

The problem with this is that the partialPath variable is supposed to include anything after the third slash.  What it ends up doing, however, is limiting the mapping itself.  This URI is mapped correctly:

```
http://localhost/webjars-locator/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js
```

But this one is not mapped to the handler at all and simply returns a 404:

```
http://localhost/webjars-locator/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css
```

The fundamental difference is simply the number of components in the path which *should* be handled by the regular expression (".+") but does not appear to be working when that portion has slashes.

If it helps, this is provided in the logs:

> 2015-03-03 23:03:53.588  INFO 15324 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/webjars-locator/{webjar}/{partialPath:.+}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity app.controllers.WebJarsLocatorController.locateWebjarAsset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>   2

Is there some type of hidden setting in Spring-Boot to enable regular expression pattern matching on RequestMappings?

Comment: Are you sure this is resolving correctly? http://localhost/webjars-locator/angular-bootstrap/datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js

Comment: I created a sample project to reproduce the issue. This URL is not working `http://localhost:8080/webjars-locator/angular-bootstrap/datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js`. But, `http://localhost:8080/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project/webjars-locator/angular-bootstrap/datetimepicker.js` is working fine. @robross - Please confirm the same.

Comment: I am absolutely positive which items are resolving correctly and which are not.  However, I did note that I had a character typo in the example and fixed it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Mithun, your project appears to be somewhat different than mine.  I do not need to put the path to my "project" in the URL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original code in the docs wasn't prepared for the extra slashes, sorry for that!

Please try this code instead:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/webjarslocator/{webjar}/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> locateWebjarAsset(@PathVariable String webjar, 
        WebRequest request) {
    try {
        String mvcPrefix = "/webjarslocator/" + webjar + "/";
        String mvcPath = (String) request.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        String fullPath = assetLocator.getFullPath(webjar, 
                mvcPath.substring(mvcPrefix.length()));
        ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource(fullPath);
        long lastModified = res.lastModified();
        if ((lastModified > 0) && request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

I will also provide an update for webjar docs shortly.

Updated 2015/08/05: Added If-Modified-Since handling

Comment: You would like to add `Last-Modified` header attribute in response to avoid the transfer of the resources every time the page is loaded.

`URLConnection conn = classPathResource.getURL().openConnection();` and then use `headers.setContentLength(conn.getContentLengthLong());` and
`headers.setLastModified(conn.getLastModified());`

Comment: @ciri-cuervo: Good point! I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I don't think it works with return `null`, cause Spring would send a **200 OK** response status and the site wouldn't load the resources. If you set the `Last-Modified` attribute in headers, Spring will automatically reply **304 Not Modified** (and not the resource) when it finds `If-Modified-Since` in the request. Look at my example: [WebJarsLocatorController.java](https://bitbucket.org/ciri-cuervo/spring-boot-with-thymeleaf/src/909ba6fc6e05e8e61077b550401472f23c523de7/src/main/java/com/example/web/WebJarsLocatorController.java?at=master)

Comment: I have tested it with Chrome and it seems to do the job fine. From what I read in the docs, checkNotModified() will transparently set the appropriate response headers (including status). Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html#checkNotModified-long-

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot have a `PathVariable` to match "the remaining part of the url". You have to use ant-style path patterns, i.e. "**" as described here:

[Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

You can then get the entire URL of the request object and extract the "remaining part".

Comment: Please refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

Comment: I have read the docs. I know that it doesn't explicitly state that a `@PathVariable` can only be applied to one element in the path, but it seems that this is the case. Nowhere in the docs could I find an example of a regexp that matches multiple path elements.

Comment: The regex is not matching multiple path variables. Just one. The link i provided takes you directly to such an example.  Similar examples can be found all over the web.  I suspect Spring Boot is to blame.  Regardless, I tested with one element and that didn't work either.

Comment: I don't get it, you have a `PathVariable` with a regex, and you want it to match "integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css", which is _more than one_ path element. The link you provided shows how it matches _one_ path element. And yes, it does work in that case.

Comment: Maybe another way of expressing this is, your regexp cannot match '/'.

Comment: I think I understand.  The example provided from webjars is inadequate.  I will use the workaround to obtain the path.