# Access a file into a folder of my project with @GetMapping

Tags: java, spring

I mean, this is what i have in my code:

```
@GetMapping("/get/player/{csvName}")
public void loadPlayers(@PathVariable String csvName) {
/*Irrelevant code here*/
}
```

This works just because the csv file is in the root of my project.

Is there any way to set the relative path of the csv file on the url?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////EDIT///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is the code of the class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/csv")
public class CsvController {
    
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FutbolApplication.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MembershipRepository memberRepository;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/get/player/{csvName}")
    public void loadPlayers(@PathVariable String csvName) {
        
        CSVReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(csvName))
                    .withSkipLines(1).build();

            String[] values;
            int i;
            int count=0;
            while ((values = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                count++;
                i=0;
                try {
                Player player = new Player(values[i++],values[i++],values[i++],Date.valueOf(values[i++]));
                System.out.println(player.getName() + "//" + player.getSurname() + "//" + player.getPosition()
                        + "//" + player.getBirthDate());
                playerRepository.save(player);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("ERROR INTENTANDO ASIGNAR LOS DATOS AL JUGADOR "+(count));
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I can to, is to insert the path of the csv instead of just the name.

At the moment my project's structure is:

```
>project
    >src
       >main
       >test
    >.Settings
    >mycsvfile.csv
```

that's why i can just type "mycsvfile.csv" in the url and it works

But this is what i'd like to get:

```
>project
    >src
       >main
       >test
    >.Settings
    >csvs
       >mycsvfile.csv
```

And get it to work by typing "/csvs/mycsvfile.csv"

Because now i just can type "https:localhost:8080/csv/get/player/mycsvfile.csv"

Is it possible?

Comment: Here, csvName is just a string variable. Nothing about the path of a file. Maybe the code you're hiding will help more with your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i've edited the post, check it out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`.

If I understood correctly, you want to send the path of the file, you want to load your Player from, via the request.

Sending a file path in the URI won't work from the get go as it will change the path of the request and it will lead to a 404 NOT FOUND.

Using `@RequestParam` is a different story, you can add full file path there.

```
@GetMapping("/get/player")
public void loadPlayers(@RequestParam String csvName) {
    /*Rest of your code here*/
}
```

This way your request would look like this:

`https://localhost:8080/csv/get/player?csvName=csvs/mycsvfile.csv`

If you really want to use `@PathVariable` to send the path of your file, then you will have to change your endpoint to work with wildcard and extract the file path from the request URI like explained by [N. Chicoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8434518/n-chicoine) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450953/send-file-path-as-pathvariable-in-spring-mvc).

And if you need to use this in multiple places you can even get a more elegant solution by implementing an annotation that makes use of the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` interface:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FilePath {

    class Resolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

        private final PathMatcher pathMatcher;

        public Resolver() {
            this.pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
            Annotation annotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(FilePath.class);
            return annotation != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modeContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
            if (servletRequest == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String patternAttribute = (String) servletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
            String mappingAttribute = (String) servletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
            return this.pathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern(patternAttribute, mappingAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will have to register the annotation in application configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new FilePath.Resolver());
    }
}
```

And finaly you can use it like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/get/player/**")
    public void loadPlayers(@FilePath String csvName) {
        /*Rest of your code here*/
    }
```

Enabling you to execute the request like:

`https://localhost:8080/csv/get/player/csvs/mycsvfile.csv`

Hope this will help you.