# How to get a path variable that is the remainder of the path in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I get my last path variable to be the remaining path? I have something like this, but it's not getting hit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path}/**",
                method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path}/**", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity upload(@PathVariable(name = "storageId") String storageId,
                             @PathVariable(name = "repositoryId") String repositoryId,
                             @PathVariable(name = "path") String path,
                             MultipartFile multipartFile)
        throws ...
{
   ...
}
```

In Jersey, I could do it easily like this:

```
@Path("{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path:.*}")
```

... but I have to migrate some code over to Spring MVC.

The problem is that if my URL is:

```
http://localhost:48080/storages/storage0/snapshots/org/foo/bar/metadata/metadata-foo/3.1-SNAPSHOT/metadata-foo-3.1-20161017.182007-1.jar
```

my `path` gets truncated to:

```
metadata/metadata-foo/3.1-SNAPSHOT/metadata-foo-3.1-20161017.182007-1.jar
```

Which is obviously incorrect, as it should be:

```
org/foo/bar/metadata/metadata-foo/3.1-SNAPSHOT/metadata-foo-3.1-20161017.182007-1.jar
```

Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125938/discussion-between-carlspring-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: Take some hints form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Any thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095340/is-it-possible-to-use-spring-mvc-with-jersey-annotations/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with the new(ish) matching algorithms that started to show up in Spring 5. You just use `{*foo}` as the path pattern.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path}/{*rest}",
                method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity upload(@PathVariable(name = "storageId") String storageId,
                             @PathVariable(name = "repositoryId") String repositoryId,
                             @PathVariable(name = "path") String path,
                             @PathVariable(name = "rest") String rest,
                             MultipartFile multipartFile)
        throws ...
{
   ...
}
```

This works by default in Webflux. With MVC you have to switch on the `PathPattern` matcher with `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=path_pattern_parser`. I understand this will be the default in Spring Boot 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path}/**",
                 method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public ResponseEntity upload(@PathVariable(name = "storageId") String storageId,
                              @PathVariable(name = "repositoryId") String repositoryId,MultipartFile multipartFile,HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ...
    {
        String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
        HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
```

Comment: Could try to print all three variables and add the examples? I'm afraid this doesn't work for me. Also, is this really the way it's done in Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes, this is really that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value?noredirect=1&lq=1