# Is it possible to use Spring MVC with Jersey annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am wondering, if it's possible to use Spring Web MVC with Jersey annotations, as I'm having a massive problem with Spring not being able to parse part variables the way Jersey can and I need to migrate some Jersey code to Spring MVC.

I have the following code in Jersey:

```
@PUT
@Path("{storageId}/{repositoryId}/{path:.*}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ARTIFACTS_DEPLOY')")
public Response upload(@PathParam("storageId") String storageId,
                       @PathParam("repositoryId") String repositoryId,
                       @PathParam("path") String path,
                       InputStream is)
{
    ...
}
```

I would like to convert this over to Spring MVC, but, like I've explained in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091229/how-to-get-a-path-variable-that-is-the-remainder-of-the-path-in-spring-mvc) post, I'm experiencing issues with parsing the path variables.

Hence, my wondering (and a separate question): is it possible to use the same Jersey annotations with Spring MVC?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee: This is an example of how to connect Jersey with Spring. I already know how to do that.

Comment: Annotations are just that: annotations. They don't do anything. Even if Spring did support JAX-RS annotations (which it doesn't), it would still have to parse their value.

Answer (score -2):

it's possible to use Spring Web MVC with Jersey annotations, try make a little sample in   [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/)  there you can check the option jersey, see how spring build this project and try in yours