# Spring MVC @PathVariable gives 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding, path-variables

I have been searching for the answer and many answers didn't solve my problem even though they solved very similar problems.

So My problem  is this : I have a path variable which may contain character "/". The same value also contains other special characters such as "." "+" "=" etc .basically all valid Base64 characters.

But Spring MVC throws 404 with logs saying no handler found. I tried using regular expressions in path variable as well but to no avail. so below id my code snippets :

```
http://localhost:8080/sale/public/viewSaleDetails/b91a03730a746a2b27e1c7bbbd94ddf6a9df593301cd96c606348df5eed235da.FkJJbOqEM8Xvhffe6FwUdQ8/mMCD4+fxpY7w5L9kbJ8=
```

is my URL. If you see it has / in path variable value. along with  "." and "+" and "=". Spring maps this correctly if I remove / between character "m" and "8". but with  / in value it just doesnt work. I tried a lot of things including character encoding filter,regex in pathvariable etc. Please help.

Also I dont want to use request parameters as far as possible.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/public/viewSaleDetails/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

is my mapping. Also the url is hit from the browser as it is without any URL encoding. I tracked it on browser network bar and it doesnt encode it as expected. I am using Spring 4.2.8 RELEASE version with java 8 and tomcat 8

Comment: i'm not sure if Spring can handle "/" in the PathVariables, i think it won't work, however you can use some url rewriter to transform your PathVariable from public/viewSaleDetails/{id}  to a RequestParam  public/viewSaleDetails?id=xx before reaching your controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is [open issue in spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12546) according matching slashes in path. And due to discussion it is not reasonable to change mathing strategy on framework level. The issue was created due to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value) and I suggest creating value resolver according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686956/7221823).

Here is example code for such resolver:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleSpringApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleSpringApp.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class SampleController {
    @RequestMapping("/records/**")
    public String getId(Id id) {
        return id.id;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new IdResolver());
    }
}

class IdResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return Id.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {    
        String basePath = ((String) webRequest.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE,
                RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST
        )).replace("**", "");
        String id = ((String) webRequest.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE,
                RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST
        )).replace(basePath, "");
        return new Id(id);
    }
}

class Id {
    public final String id;

    Id(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```