# Url Binding in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

i have been strugling since 4 days but did not found the solution for how to bind the url in Spring Boot with gradle.

I have a url as, http://loalhost:8080/blog/post.html?pid=2&ptitle=abc

I want this url to be shown as below with html and (?), 
http://localhost:8080/blog/post/2/abc

Is there any way to do that. I don't want to use tucky urlrewriter. All my html files are placed in webapp folder.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What kind of code (which annotations?) is responsible for the "2/abc" part? Do you use Spring MVC?

Comment: I am using @RequestMapping. Basically rest api's to achive this. Yeah i use Spring MVC

Comment: Are you using `@RequestParam` to get the `pid` and `ptitle` values? Try using `@PathVariable` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value

Comment: I am not having any trouble using values, but i want to make my url seo friendly without .html and (?).

Comment: So what's the issue then?

Comment: I got it working with thymeleaf. Problem was that, i wanted seo friendly url. So for that i found thymeleaf to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

if your have a POST method in your `@RestController` to create a post blog:

```
@PostMapping("/blog/post/{pid}/{ptitle}")
public void create(@PathVariable("pid") String pid, @PathVariable("ptitle") String ptitle) {
// a repo save call
}
```

(I supposed that you use last spring boot version)

Comment: you can see official doc spring.io to be more rest compliant with your uri