# How to correctly escape '/' in Spring Rest @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest

In Spring Boot 1.5.4 I have a request mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph/{graphId}/details/{iri:.+}", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public JSONObject getGraph(@PathVariable Long graphId, 
                           @PathVariable String iri) {
    log.debug("Details called for graph ID {} for IRI {}", graphId, iri);
    return detailsService.getDetails(graphId, iri);
}
```

Accessing

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http%3Anthnth33

works fine and the server maps the request correctly and the code returns the expected result

But accessing

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http%3A%2F%2Fserverurl.net%2Fv1%2Fus%2Fh.schumacher%408tsch.net%2Fn%2FLouSchumacher

gives a **bad server request** (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)). The request mapping to the end point isn't even done in that case.

Obviously the slash '/' encoded as %2F (using encodeURIComponent()) causes trouble. Why? What am I missing? How should uri parameter then be encoded?

The question is not only about how to extract PathVariables but more on how to force String to recognize the correct mapping.

Comment: Instead of GET API , make it a POST API request and send the URI in the request body. As a thumb rule whenever you have large number of parameters to pass , POST comes much more handy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Comment: Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value) is related but the question is not duplicate in the sense that this question is about mapping of the Rest endpoint and less about the extraction of the PathVariables afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your example is how Spring is doing path matching. The URL you have provided as example

```
http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http%3A%2F%2Fserverurl.net%2Fv1%2Fus%2Fh.schumacher%408tsch.net%2Fn%2FLouSchumacher
```

will be decoded into by container

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http://serverurl.net/v1/us/h.schumacher@8tsch.net/n/LouSchumacher

before processing by Spring matcher. This makes matche think that this only `http:` corresponds `{iri:.+}` and as later goes `/` so it is some longer path you don't have a mapping for.

The approach described here should work for you: [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph/{graphId}/details/**", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public JSONObject getGraph(@PathVariable Long graphId, 
                           HttpServletRequest request) {
    String iri = (String) request.getAttribute(
        HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    log.debug("Details called for graph ID {} for IRI {}", graphId, iri);
    return detailsService.getDetails(graphId, iri);
}
```

Comment: This helps, but the mapping to the Rest endpoint does work that way if I do NOT encode the URL with encodeURIComponent(). If I do encode with encodeURIComponent() the mapping is not recognized and I get a "Bad Request (400)" error. 

So the mapping for
http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http://serverurl.net/v1/us/h.schumacher@8tsch.net/n/LouSchumacher 
works but for http://localhost:9000/api/v1/graph/2/details/http%3A%2F%2Fserverurl.net%2Fv1%2Fus%2Fh.schumacher%408tsch.net%2Fn%2FLouSchumacher doesn't.