# Spring MVC @GetMapping("/v1/**") with ANT wildcards: how to get full path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Consider a Spring MVC `@RestController` with a `@GetMapping` which maps to `/v1/**` to handle all sub-paths.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/**", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView handle(String fullPathInMethodArg) {
        ...
        String fullPathInLocalVar = ...;
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I retreive the full path?

Ideally, I want to retrieve it as an argument in the method: `String fullPathInMethodArg`.

Alternatively, I want to retrieve it as a local variable: `String fullPathInLocalVar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

```
@RequestMapping("/v1/**")
public void foo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String fullPath = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String subPath = StringUtils.removeStart(fullPath, "/v1");
    ...
}
```

[Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Comment: Apparently there was a rejected change request: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14032