# Get PathVariables, RequestParams , RequestBody in a service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, httprequest

I want to get all parameters (not need for headers) from an httpRequest in à spring service component

I'm using Spring boot, look at this example :

```
private final MyService myService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/processform/{process_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> runForm( String process_id,
                                               @RequestParam String className,
                                               @RequestBody(required = false) IupicsFormVO vo) {
        return myService.run(process_id, className, vo);
    }
```

This controller generate this curl (without headers):

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://localhost:8087/processform/119?className=com.stackOverflow.question.ClassName.java' \
  -d '{  
"name" : "Name",
"age" : "Age"
}'
```

Now what i need is to get all parameters from this URL (may be with injecting `HttpServletRequest` )

The expected result is kind of :

```
{  
   "process_id":"119",
   "className":"com.stackOverflow.question.ClassName.java",
   "body":{  
      "name":"Name",
      "age":"Age"
   }
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937448/3809391) example,

```
String finalPath = apm.extractPathWithinPattern(bestMatchPattern, path
```

but when i use'it i got always en empty finalPath Thanks for your time

Comment: Why can't you use it? Please clarify

Comment: always got an empty finalString

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. What do you need to extract from path? If there are any additional parameters (with `?name=value`) just specify them with `@RequestParam`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a variable in the path to use `@PathVariable`. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processform/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
LinkedHashMap<String, String> runForm(@PathVariable("id") String process_id, ...
```

Comment: this is not hat i want, the controller work fine i just forgot to copy it i will update my question, but i want later to get those information from HTTPRequest

Answer (score 0):

Your path should have path variable placeholder. `/processform/{process_id}`. Also you need to specify `request parameter`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processform/{process_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> runForm(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("process_id") String process_id, @RequestParam("name") String lassName,@RequestParam("age") String age,
                                               @RequestBody(required = false) IupicsFormVO vo) {
        return myService.run(process_id, className, vo);
    }
```

For more details about [Path variable and Request parameter](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/10/differences-requestparam-pathvariable-annotations-spring-mvc.html)  you can have a look at this tutorial.

EDIT:
If you want to get these attributes from the request, then first parameter will be `HttpServletRequest request` in your controller method. Pass the `request` parameter to your service and there you can user `request.getParameter("paramName")` and `request.getAttribute("attributeName")` to access the values.

Comment: this is not hat i want, the controller work fine i just forgot to copy it i will update my question, but i want later to get those information from HTTPRequest